# Hibernate updation not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using following method to update data in database.

```
     String hql = "UPDATE EmployeeSalary set salary = :sl,"
                        + "monthYr=:dt "
                        + "WHERE id =:id and client.id=:cid";
            for (EmployeeSalary e : eList) {
                Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

                query.setParameter("sl", e.getSalary());
                query.setParameter("dt", e.getMonthYr());
                query.setParameter("id", e.getId());
                query.setParameter("cid", e.getClient().getId());

                int result = query.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("result is " + result);
                if (eAttList.size() % 20 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
```

Is there any problem with code.

On execution it is showing

result is 0

How to resolve above problem.

Comment: At first view propably the where clause does not hit any record. Trace id and cid and do a manual select against the db to check if this records really exists.

Comment: @xrcwrn this piece of code looks fine, need to make sure what is the SQL generated at backend, also `id` and `cid` how are they generated , is everything under same transaction. Does records present in DB.

Comment: @ankur-singhal Record existed in db. Manual updation is also working in hql query brower. here it is not working

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct) about update queries says:

> No "Forms of join syntax", either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.

Your query seems to violate this rule: `client.id=:cid` is an implicit join to the client entity.

Note that you're making your life difficult. You could simply get the entity by ID from the session (using `Session.get()`), and update it. Update queries are useful to update many rows at once.

Comment: I am not getting you fully could you please provide any example